# throw new TypeORMError(`Query Builder is not supported by MongoDB.`

Tags: typescript, mongodb, version, typeorm, upgrade

I am updating version typescript and typeorm.I have an error on npm run time: 'Any one please help.what happened here
code:
This is my error

```
E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:561
            throw new TypeORMError(`Query Builder is not supported by MongoDB.`)
                  ^
TypeORMError: Query Builder is not supported by MongoDB.
    at DataSource.createQueryBuilder (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:561:19)
    at MongoEntityManager.createQueryBuilder (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:200:36)
    at MongoEntityManager.findBy (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:1094:21)
    at MongoRepository.findBy (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\repository\MongoRepository.ts:103:29)
    at Function.<anonymous> (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\controller\ScheduleController.ts:36:47)
    at step (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\controller\ScheduleController.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\controller\ScheduleController.ts:14:53)
    at E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\controller\ScheduleController.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version\src\controller\ScheduleController.ts:4:12)

E:\amazonreposts\amazon_version>
```

data-source.ts

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  "type": "mongodb",
  "url": process.env.DB_URL,
  "useNewUrlParser": false,
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  entities: [Admin, Store, ReportType, Job,Etest],
  migrations: [
    PopulateReportTypes1649246273594,
    IndexJobsByCreated1650879874598,
    IndexesOnSearchFields1650970385870,
    StoreSellerIdSparseIndex1651850441866,
    JobsWorkerSearchIndex1655719231625,
    //CreateEtest1689781759578
  ],
  subscribers: []
})
```

```
import { RecurrenceRule, scheduleJob, Job as SJob, Range } from 'node-schedule'
import { AppDataSource } from '../data-source'
import { Job } from '../entity/Job'
import { ReportType } from '../entity/ReportType'
import { Store } from '../entity/Store'
import { AMZWorkerController } from './AMZWorkerController'

export class ScheduleController {
  private static storeRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Store)
  private static reportTypeRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(ReportType)
  private static jobsRepository = AppDataSource.getMongoRepository(Job)
  private static stores: Map<string, Store> = new Map()
  private static reportTypes20Minutes: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes30Minutes: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypesHourly: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes2Hours: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes3Hours: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes4Hours: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes6Hours: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes12Hours: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypesDaily: ReportType[]
  private static reportTypes2Days: ReportType[]
  private static storeSchedules20Minutes: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules30Minutes: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedulesHourly: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules2Hours: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules3Hours: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules4Hours: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules6Hours: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules12Hours: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedulesDaily: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeSchedules2Days: Map<string, SJob> = new Map()
  private static storeWorkers: Map<string, AMZWorkerController> = new Map()

  public static async init() {
    const stores = await this.storeRepository.findBy({
      enabled: true
    })
    await this.populateReportTypes()
    stores.forEach(store => {
      this.addStore(store)
    })
  }

  private static async populateReportTypes() {
    this.reportTypes20Minutes = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '20minutes'
    })
    this.reportTypes30Minutes = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '30minutes'
    })
    this.reportTypesHourly = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: 'hourly'
    })
    this.reportTypes2Hours = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '2hours'
    })
    this.reportTypes3Hours = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '3hours'
    })
    this.reportTypes4Hours = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '4hours'
    })
    this.reportTypes6Hours = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '6hours'
    })
    this.reportTypes12Hours = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '12hours'
    })
    this.reportTypesDaily = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: 'daily'
    })
    this.reportTypes2Days = await this.reportTypeRepository.findBy({
      defaultEnabled: true,
      schedule: '2days'
    })
  }

  public static async addStore(store: Store) {
    if (this.stores.has(store.id.toHexString())) {
      return false
    }
    // save store in the map
    this.stores.set(store.id.toHexString(), store)

    // setup schedules

    // 20 minutes
    let rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.minute = new Range(0, 60, 20)
    this.storeSchedules20Minutes.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes20Minutes.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 30 minutes
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.minute = new Range(0, 60, 30)
    this.storeSchedules30Minutes.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes30Minutes.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // hourly
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedulesHourly.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypesHourly.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 2 hours
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = new Range(0, 24, 2)
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules2Hours.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes2Hours.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 3 hours
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = new Range(0, 24, 3)
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules3Hours.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes3Hours.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 4 hours
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = new Range(0, 24, 4)
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules4Hours.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes4Hours.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 6 hours
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = new Range(0, 24, 6)
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules6Hours.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes6Hours.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 12 hours
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = new Range(0, 24, 12)
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules12Hours.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes12Hours.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // daily
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.hour = 0
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedulesDaily.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypesDaily.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    // 2 days
    rule = new RecurrenceRule()
    rule.date = new Range(1, 32, 2)
    rule.hour = 0
    rule.minute = 0
    this.storeSchedules2Days.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.reportTypes2Days.forEach(reportType => {
          this.addJob(store, reportType)
        })
      })
    )

    this.createMissingReports(store)
    this.storeWorkers.set(
      store.id.toHexString(),
      new AMZWorkerController(store)
    )
    console.log('Store: ' + store.storeName + ', schedules set.')
  }

  private static async createMissingReports(store: Store) {
    const gtedate = new Date()
    const ltedate = new Date()
    const hour = new Date().getHours()
    const minute = new Date().getMinutes()

    // create missing jobs

    // 20 minutes
    gtedate.setMinutes(minute - (minute % 20))
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes20Minutes) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 30 minutes
    gtedate.setMinutes(minute - (minute % 30))
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes30Minutes) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // hourly
    gtedate.setMinutes(0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypesHourly) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 2hours
    gtedate.setHours(hour - (hour % 2), 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes2Hours) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 3hours
    gtedate.setHours(hour - (hour % 3), 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes3Hours) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 4hours
    gtedate.setHours(hour - (hour % 4), 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes4Hours) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 6hours
    gtedate.setHours(hour - (hour % 6), 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes6Hours) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 12hours
    gtedate.setHours(hour - (hour % 12), 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes6Hours) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // daily
    gtedate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypesDaily) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }

    // 2 days
    const day = gtedate.getDate()
    gtedate.setDate(day - ((day + 1) % 2))
    for (const reportType of this.reportTypes2Days) {
      const existingJob = await this.jobsRepository.findOneBy({
        storeId: store.id,
        reportTypeId: reportType.id,
        created: {
          $gte: gtedate,
          $lte: ltedate
        }
      })
      if (!existingJob) {
        this.addJob(store, reportType)
      }
    }
  }

  public static async refreshReports() {
    await this.populateReportTypes()
    this.stores.forEach(store => {
      this.createMissingReports(store)
    })
  }

  public static async removeStore(store: Store) {
    if (!this.stores.has(store.id.toHexString())) {
      return false
    }
    this.storeSchedules20Minutes.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules20Minutes.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules30Minutes.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules30Minutes.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedulesHourly.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedulesHourly.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules2Hours.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules2Hours.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules3Hours.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules3Hours.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules4Hours.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules4Hours.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules6Hours.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules6Hours.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules12Hours.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules12Hours.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedulesDaily.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedulesDaily.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeSchedules2Days.get(store.id.toHexString()).cancel()
    this.storeSchedules2Days.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.storeWorkers.get(store.id.toHexString()).stop()
    this.storeWorkers.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    this.stores.delete(store.id.toHexString())
    console.log('Store: ' + store.storeName + ', schedules removed.')
  }

  private static async addJob(store: Store, reportType: ReportType) {
    if (!reportType.singleMarketplace) {
      console.log(
        'Added Job:\n reportType: ' +
          reportType.name +
          ',\n store: ' +
          store.storeName +
          ',\n Marketplaces: ',
        store.marketplaces
      )
      await this.jobsRepository.save(
        this.jobsRepository.create({
          storeId: store.id,
          reportTypeId: reportType.id,
          created: new Date(),
          updated: new Date(),
          marketplaces: store.marketplaces,
          flow: reportType.flow,
          state: 'new'
        })
      )
    } else {
      if (!store.marketplaces) return
      for (let i = 0; i < store.marketplaces?.length; i++) {
        console.log(
          'Added Job:\n reportType: ' +
            reportType.name +
            ',\n store: ' +
            store.storeName +
            ',\n Marketplace: ',
          store.marketplaces[i]
        )
        await this.jobsRepository.save(
          this.jobsRepository.create({
            storeId: store.id,
            reportTypeId: reportType.id,
            created: new Date(),
            updated: new Date(),
            marketplaces: [store.marketplaces[i]],
            flow: reportType.flow,
            state: 'new'
          })
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

please help me. I tried to debug the code.
I am not able to find out the soluction for it.
after upgrade typeorm version. I am facing issue
how I can solve it.

Comment: see https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3492

Comment: Thank you, I checked that issue. the issue is in my code. According to the version in the code have some query issues. I solved all query one by one.